# Creating Geodatabase Script Creator using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, python-script-tool

I have been working on and compiling different code snippets to create a GDB Generator.  Most of the code logic I understand, but there is some that I can't grasp.  Below is the code.

Code:

```
#import modules and create parameters of tool
import arcpy

currentdir = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
gdbnames = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
inputlyr = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
```

```
#Function to Run script

def gdbbuilder(currentdir, gdbnames, inputlyr):
    arcpy.AddMessage("...Starting Function")

    ## folder name for the project
    projectname = currentdir.split("\\")[-1]
    arcpy.AddMessage(projectname)
    folder_path = currentdir.rsplit("\\", 1)[0]
    arcpy.AddMessage(folder_path)

    ## if the directory already exists, delete it
    if arcpy.Exists(currentdir):
            arcpy.Delete_management(currentdir)

    ## create the folder
    arcpy.CreateFolder_management(folder_path, projectname)

    ## list of gdb names
    gdb_lst = gdbnames.replace("'", "").split(";")

    ## shapefile name without the shp to name the feature class
    ## make sure the feature class is a valid name
    fc_name = inputlyr.split("\\")[-1].replace(".shp", "").replace(" ", "_")

    ## for each gdb in the input gdb list
    for gdbname in gdb_lst:
        ## the name of the gdb to create
        newgdbname = "{0}_{1}".format(projectname,gdbname)
        ## the new gdb path
        gdb_path = "{0}\\{1}.gdb".format(currentdir, newgdbname)

        arcpy.AddMessage("Creating GDB: {0}".format(gdb_path))
        arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(currentdir, newgdbname)
        arcpy.AddMessage("Converting Shapefile to Feature Class")
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inputlyr, gdb_path, fc_name)

gdbbuilder(currentdir, gdbnames, inputlyr)
```

Question:

My question revolves around the purpose of using "\" as input to the .split parameter in conjunction with the [-1] index.

```
 ## folder name for the project
    projectname = currentdir.split("\\")[-1]
    arcpy.AddMessage(projectname)
    folder_path = currentdir.rsplit("\\", 1)[0]
    arcpy.AddMessage(folder_path)
```

Also. Why does the `.splitmethod` within `gdb_list` variable have `(";")` as the input value?

Within the `fc_name` variable why does replace method parameter value look like this to work
`fc_name = inputlyr.split("\\")[-1].replace(".shp", "").replace(" ", "_")`

Comment: This is actually awful code. Best practice is to use `os.path` functions to parse paths. In this case, that would be `os.path.basename` to extract the terminal name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[-1]` means the last element of a list/tuple/iterable. So `"a\\b\\c".split("\\")[-1] == "c"`.  But as @Vince notes, you're better off using proper path parsing - e.g. `projectname = os.path.basename(currentdir)`

`gdbnames` is likely a MultiValue parameter. ArcGIS turns the multiple values into a single string by wrapping values in single quotes if they have a space and separating by a ";".  So if you selected 2 GDBs in the the geoprocessing tool:

1. D:\Some Path\some.gdb
2. D:\Data\another.gdb

`arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)` will give you `"'D:\\Some Path\\some.gdb';D:\Data\another.gdb"`

So `gdbnames.replace("'", "").split(";")` will return `["D:\\Some Path\\some.gdb", "D:\Data\another.gdb"]`